# How I can do this code to work proper and how I can do this code more optimum?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables: gal and TCPD_personel_COPY. I want to insert in TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY, that users which are in gal and not exists yet in TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY whit condition `gal.country='Germany'` . But I have also the conditions  :

```
(gal.name not like '07_%' 
                 gal.name not like 'TR_%' 
                 gal.name not like 'ST_%' 
                  gal.name not like 'KB_%'  
                   gal.name not like 'HS_%'  
                    gal.name is not null)
```

to this condition I don't have the country specified.

I try to use the next code but it doesn't work proper:

How I can do this code to work proper?

Comment: Could you be more precise about what the code is doing that it shouldn't do, and what it should do that it doesn't please? Are you getting an error message? Is it doing something unintended? Not doing all the things you did expect?

Comment: If you are using an Oracle DB, you can use `MERGE` to achieve this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Comment: this cod not doing all the things I did expect , insert more rows  I did expect .

Comment: where in gal not exists name or exists name like '07_%' don't insert in TCPD_PERSONEL_COPY.... I expect to go and compare the email for users which matching the condition gal.country='Germany'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `and`, not `or`.

You are looking for all the data, except for the items that don't start with a given phrase. So you want the ones where name doesn't start with `07_`, nor `TR_`, nor  `ST_`... But you're using `not like`, so what you need to ask is "Name doesn't start with 07_, and it doesn't start with TR_, and it doesn't start with ST_, ...".

Using `or` instead of `and` means that you always get everything, since if something starts with `07_`, it can't start with `TR_` as well, that's simply impossible - and you select all for which at least one of those conditions fit - since the conditions are "mutually inclusive", `true` is the only possible result.

Comment: Thank you!  I have another question: I can do this code more optimal ?

Answer (score 1):

Change this part:

```
where (gal.name not like '07_%' or 
       gal.name not like 'TR_%' or
       gal.name not like 'ST_%' or
       gal.name not like 'KB_%'  or
       gal.name not like 'HS_%'  or
       gal.name is not null)
```

These should be ANDs not ORs.

If the name is not null NO MATTER WHAT THE VALUE IS it's going to be selected because the ORs mean ANY ONE OF THOSE CONDITIONS mush be met for it to be true.

Comment: Thank you!  I have another question: I can do this code more optimal ?